# VC++ create Cdialog Class Assertion error

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm a complete noob with Visual Studio, it's probably a stupid mistake.

I'm only trying to instantiate a Cdialog class, I'm making a dll that in the end will need to had some activeX commands in the Window.

I'm tried several ways to instantiate, but I always getting an assertion error.

So in my calldllclass.h I had:

```
#pragma once
__declspec(dllexport) long init();
```

in my class that extend Cdialog:

```
//{{AFX_INCLUDES()
//}}AFX_INCLUDES

class CMyclass: public CDialog{

#include "resource.h"

public:
    CMyclass(CWnd* pParent = NULL)
    : CDialog(100, pParent){
        //{{AFX_DATA_INIT(CMyclass)
        //}}AFX_DATA_INIT   
    };  // standard constructor
    virtual ~CMyclass(){};
    long calc();
// Dialog Data
    //{{AFX_DATA(CMyclass)
    //}}AFX_DATA

    // ClassWizard generated virtual function overrides
    //{{AFX_VIRTUAL(CMyclass)
    protected:
    //}}AFX_VIRTUAL

protected:
    // Generated message map functions
    //{{AFX_MSG(CMyclass)
    //}}AFX_MSG
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()   

};
//{{AFX_INSERT_LOCATION}}
```

I created an Resource Class:

```
#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "afxres.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// English (U.S.) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
#ifdef _WIN32
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
#pragma code_page(1252)
#endif //_WIN32

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE MOVEABLE PURE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE MOVEABLE PURE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""afxres.h""\r\n"
    "\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE MOVEABLE PURE 
BEGIN
    "#define _AFX_NO_SPLITTER_RESOURCES\r\n"
    "#define _AFX_NO_OLE_RESOURCES\r\n"
    "#define _AFX_NO_TRACKER_RESOURCES\r\n"
    "#define _AFX_NO_PROPERTY_RESOURCES\r\n"
    "\r\n"
    "#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)\r\n"
    "#ifdef _WIN32\r\n"
    "LANGUAGE 9, 1\r\n"
    "#pragma code_page(1252)\r\n"
    "#endif //_WIN32\r\n"
    "#include ""res\\SimpleVC6SampleEvent.rc2""  // non-Microsoft Visual C++ edited resources\r\n"
    "#include ""afxres.rc""         // Standard components\r\n"
    "#endif\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED




/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog
//

IDD_ABOUTBOX DIALOG DISCARDABLE  0, 0, 0, 0
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
BEGIN
END




#endif    // English (U.S.) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

and finally in my cpp I had:

```
// SIMPLEDIALOGDLL.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "myclass.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include "dll2export.h"


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyclass, CDialog)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CMyclass)
    //}}AFX_MSG
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


long init(){  

    AfxEnableControlContainer();
    CoInitializeEx(NULL,COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());

    CMyclass * obj = new CMyclass();

    //obj->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
    obj->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

    long res = obj->calc();
    return (long) obj;
}

long CMyclass::calc(){
    return 1+1;
}
```

When obj->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW); is called I get an
Debug Assertion Failed!
winocc.cpp Line 329

```
BOOL CWnd::ShowWindow(int nCmdShow)
{
    ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd) || (m_pCtrlSite != NULL));

    if (m_pCtrlSite == NULL)
        return ::ShowWindow(m_hWnd, nCmdShow);
    else
        return m_pCtrlSite->ShowWindow(nCmdShow);
}
```

a little update I put  after showWindow it returns 1400

```
   DWORD dw = GetLastError();
```

add answer sugenstion
I had this to init method

```
AfxEnableControlContainer();
CoInitializeEx(NULL,COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState( ));

CMyclass *obj = new CMyclass();

if(obj->Create(100)){
    obj->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();
}else{
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();
}
```

Now I'm having in obj->Create(100)); objcore.cpp Line: 40

Comment: I don't see a call to [`CDialog::Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhth57kd.aspx) anywhere.  You need to create a dialog before you can show it.

Comment: this is not enought?           CMyclass(CWnd* pParent = NULL)
    : CDialog(100, pParent){

Comment: @RoyBean That creates the CDialog object but it does not create the window. You must call Create to create a modeless dialog window.

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP I added  CMyclass(CWnd* pParent = NULL)
 : CDialog(100,pParent){
  //{{AFX_DATA_INIT(CMyclass)
  //}}AFX_DATA_INIT 
  CDialog::Create(100,pParent); 

results in an assertions fail also

Comment: That's probably because dialog template "100" does not exist. I would recommend you read some "getting started" tutorial on MFC.

Comment: @Nikolay can you show me a link tuturial for Cdialog and dll creation?, in resource.h the header of my Resource i defined #define IDD_ABOUTBOX                    100 and in  Resouyrce symbles appears with the in use flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was right,

after many many hours, I went to change the compiler options of the Visual Studio and in Debug Information Format put Program Database (/Zi)

That fix it for me

Comment: Don't call it a solution, unless you know **why** it is.

Comment: lol, that worked for me, if any Visual Studio VC++ expert knows an explanation, I will love it to ear-it, I put a question and solved my problem, if you don't accept, is not my problem.

Comment: Your code is wrong. You have a bug. You failed to diagnose, why the assertion failed, and simply tried random things, until one of them made the application appear to work. By pure coincidence. I'm flagging this answer to be deleted as *"Not an answer"*.

Comment: Do what you want, So changing the program settings is not a valid solution now, LOL!

Comment: Not analyzing the bug is definitely not a valid solution. The assertion failed, because `m_hWnd` is not a valid window handle, or `m_pCtrlSite` is a `nullptr`. Why? Randomly changing compiler settings will merely **mask** the bug. Masking a bug is not regarded as a valid solution to any given programming problem.

Comment: So a compiler settings is not an important configuration?

Comment: It is. But if you cannot answer **why** changing this particular setting (presumably) fixed the bug, and how, your answer is not an answer. So far you have not made any attempt at explaining, why this is the case. I flagged this answer as *"Not an answer"*, and hope to get this cleaned out in a reasonably timely fashion.

Answer (score 1):

@ScottMcP-MVP is right, modeless dialog boxes need a call to the [Create method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhth57kd.aspx).

Also, according to the [MSDN docs on the constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zkyyhxw.aspx),

> To construct a modeless dialog box, **use the protected form of the
>   CDialog constructor**. The constructor is protected because you must
>   derive your own dialog-box class to implement a modeless dialog box.
>   Construction of a modeless dialog box is a two-step process. First
>   call the constructor; then call the Create member function to create a
>   resource-based dialog box...

So declare your class like `CMyclass() : CDialog() {...}` and use the following code to display it:

```
CMyclass * obj = new CMyclass();
if (obj->Create(100))
    obj->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
else
{ << error >>
}
```

P.S.: don't forget to delete the variable at the end of your program!

Comment: I had this to init method

AfxEnableControlContainer();
    CoInitializeEx(NULL,COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState( ));
    
 CMyclass *obj = new CMyclass();
 
 if(obj->Create(100)){
  obj->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
  DWORD dw = GetLastError();
 }else{
  DWORD dw = GetLastError();
 }

Now I'm having in obj->Create(100)); objcore.cpp Line: 40

Comment: could you check if `obj` is NULL? that could happen if record ID #100 is not in your resource file -- I noticed that you have declared your dialog box as `IDD_ABOUTBOX`, is that symbol `#define`d as 100? Better to add a check for `obj == NULL` and change the next line to `if (obj->Create(IDD_ABOUTBOX))`